# Scipy Normaltest how is it used?

Tags: python, scipy

I need to use normaltest in scipy for testing if the dataset is normal distributet. But I cant seem to find any good examples how to use [`scipy.stats.normaltest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html#scipy.stats.normaltest).

My dataset has more than 100 values.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
In [12]: import scipy.stats as stats

In [13]: x = stats.norm.rvs(size = 100)

In [14]: stats.normaltest(x)
Out[14]: (1.627533590094232, 0.44318552909231262)
```

[`normaltest`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html#scipy.stats.normaltest) returns a 2-tuple of the chi-squared statistic, and the associated p-value. Given the null hypothesis that `x` came from a normal distribution, the p-value represents the probability that a chi-squared statistic that large (or larger) would be seen.

If the p-val is very small, it means it is unlikely that the data came from a normal distribution. For example:

```
In [15]: y = stats.uniform.rvs(size = 100)

In [16]: stats.normaltest(y)
Out[16]: (31.487039026711866, 1.4543748291516241e-07)
```

Comment: How do we quantify "very small" here?

Comment: It is an arbitrary choice: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55693/842. Just be sure to you decide what your signficance level is *before* applying a statistical test.

Answer (score 13):

First i found out that scipy.stats.normaltest is almost the same. The mstats library is used for masked arrays. Arrays where you can mark values as invalid and not taken into the calculation.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from scipy.stats import mstats

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 7, 3]) #The array needs to be larger than 20, just an example
mx = ma.masked_array(x, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
z,pval = mstats.normaltest(mx)

if(pval < 0.055):
    print "Not normal distribution"
```

> "Traditionally, in statistics, you need a p-value of less than 0.05 to
> reject the null hypothesis." - [http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/72065.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171114162940/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/72065.html)

Comment: Why `< 0.055` instead of `< 0.05`?

Comment: If the p-val is very small, it means it is unlikely that the data came from a normal distribution. 0.05 is the standard threshold, but to be more certain you can raise the certainty like 0.055 or something else. Its just a threshold of saying yes it is a normal distribution.

Comment: The Demz, raising the threshold to 0.055 would mean less certainty that the data came from a normal distribution. You would want to lower your p value threshold below the standard 0.05 to decrease the chances of erroneously rejecting the null hypothesis that the distribution is normal.